# Disable animate bottom navigation when selected same position

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

**Hello**, i have question/problem about **animate bottom navigation**, How i can **disable animate bottom navigation** when i selected same position.

- Image 1. this is a ui
- Image 2. when I press the same selected item again, it will do an animation again.

How to prevent the animation again, when i pressing the same item?
my problem like this:
**thanks**..

[image: 1. this is a ui]
[image: 2. when I press the same item again, it will do an animation.]

---

---

Comment: not!!, this is not same with my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy when using a NavController, just call

```
onNavigationItemReselectedListener{ }
```

on it, if you don't put anything in it nothing will happen, which is what you want